# deducing $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ from uniform norm

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $X$ is a Locally Compact Hausdorff Space, let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions that is compactly supported, and $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Then for all $\epsilon>0$, we have $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ if $x\notin supp(f_n)$.

I am not too familiar with properties of uniform norm; I am not sure how the conclusion was drawn. I am thinking, for $\epsilon>0$, we have some $N>0$ and $\|f_n-f\|=\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in X\}<\epsilon$, for all $n>N$. So, we fix $x\in X$, then we have $|f(x)|\leq\|f\|<\|f-f_n\|<\epsilon$? I think I am missing some properties of the sup norm to see this through?

Comment: the statement is false: take $f_n=f=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ for all $n$, then $\|f_n-f\|=0$ for all $n$ but $|f_n(x)|=1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$

Comment: @Masacroso Hi sorry, I think I forgot some condition , Ive updated it.

Comment: When $x\not\in supp(f_n)$ one has $|f(x)|=|f(x)-f_n(x)|$

Comment: Thanks, I usually get stuck on trivial things like this for hours.